# PIL - apply the same operation to every pixel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I create an image and fill the pixels:

```
img = Image.new( 'RGB', (2000,2000), "black") # create a new black image
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for i in range(img.size[0]):    # for every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
      #do some stuff that requires i and j as parameter
```

Can this be done more elegant (and may be faster, since theoretically the loops are parallelizable)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: I will first answer the question, then propose an, in my opinion, better alternative*

### Answering the question

It is hard to give advice without knowing what changes you intend to apply and whether the loading of the image as a PIL image is part of the question or a given.

- More elegant in Python-speak typically means using list comprehensions
- For parallelization, you would look at something like the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module or [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)

Depending on your method of creating / loading in images, the `list_of_pixels = list(img.getdata())` and `img.putdata(new_list_of_pixels)` functions may be of interest to you.

An example of what this might look like:

```
from PIL import Image
from multiprocessing import Pool

img = Image.new( 'RGB', (2000,2000), "black")

# a function that fixes the green component of a pixel to the value 50
def update_pixel(p):
    return (p[0], 50, p[2])

list_of_pixels = list(img.getdata())
pool = Pool(4)
new_list_of_pixels = pool.map(update_pixel, list_of_pixels)
pool.close()
pool.join()
img.putdata(new_list_of_pixels)
```

However, I don't think that is a good idea... When you see loops (and list comprehensions) over thousands of elements in Python and you have performance on your mind, you can be sure there is a library that will make this faster.

### Better Alternative

First, a quick pointer to the [Channel Operations module](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html),
Since you don't specify the kind of pixel operation you intend to do and you clearly already know about the PIL library, I'll assume you're aware of it and it doesn't do what you want.

Then, any moderately complex matrix manipulation in Python will benefit from pulling in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) or [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/)...

Pure numpy example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#black image
img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
#show
plt.imshow(img)
#make it green
img[:,:, 1] = 50
#show
plt.imshow(img)
```

Since you are just working with a standard numpy.ndarray, you can use any of the available functionalities, such as np.vectorize, apply, map etc. To show a similar solution as above with the update_pixel function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#black image
img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
#show
plt.imshow(img)
#make it green
def update_pixel(p):
    return (p[0], 50, p[2])
green_img = np.apply_along_axis(update_pixel, 2, img)
#show
plt.imshow(green_img)
```

One more example, this time calculating the image content directly from the indexes, instead of from existing image pixel content (no need to create an empty image first):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calc_pixel(x,y):
    return np.array([100-x, x+y, 100-y])

img = np.frompyfunc(calc_pixel, 2, 1).outer(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))    
plt.imshow(np.array(img.tolist()))
#note: I don't know any other way to convert a 2D array of arrays to a 3D array...
```

And, low and behold, scipy has methods to read and write images and inbetween, you can just use numpy to manipulate them as "classic" mult-dimensional arrays. (`scipy.misc.imread` depends on PIL, by the way)

[More example code.](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. a few further questions: @1st variant: parallelizing every pixel seems inefficient - only the outer loop seems more appropriate. the numpy alternative looks also good, but how can i make the assigment `img[:,:, 1] = 50` dependent from the actual indices? i am quite new to python and could not find an examle (mostly because of lack of correct search terms i guess . how is this `img[:,:, 1]` kind of access pattern called?)

Comment: this is called slicing (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). In this case, it basically says to, for each row and each column replace the second of three color values -read: green- by 50)

Index 1 means the second value because Python indexes are 0-based

Comment: If you're new to PIL, I would definitely recommend to look at the Channel Operations module I mentioned, it might do what you need

Comment: channel operations does not do what i want. atm i am just playing around calculating interference pattern and fractals and was wondering how to efficiently/elegant/pythonish writing down something like `foreach x,y in img: img[x,y] = calc(x,y)`

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Maybe can you use [`numpy.ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)?

Comment: ah, yes, should have seen this question coming... Apologies :-) See updated answer

Comment: ok, one more ... Not sure what I was thinking before, but this time you get indexes :-) I think I was a bit distracted due to starting out with a black image...