# Python Tkinter perlin noise animation is very slow

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to animate a 2D perlin noise in the 3rd dimension using Tkinter un Python 2.7.
It's all working, but the performances are **very** low (about 2 fps).

I think that the problem is in the "animate" function, in which I create a new image every time I update the noise.
How can I achieve a good frame rate? In this code the image is 640x480px, but I need it to be at least 1080x720px.
I'm open to every type of suggestions (even changing the GUI library).

```
from Tkinter import *
from noise import snoise3, pnoise3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading

class Noise:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.w = 640
        self.h = 480
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width = self.w, height = self.h)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.img = Image.new("1",(self.w,self.h))
        self.pix = self.img.load()
        self.z = 0
        octv = 8
        freq = 16.0 * octv;
        for y in xrange(self.h):
            for x in xrange(self.w):
                self.pix[x,y] = int(snoise3(x/freq,y/freq,self.z,octaves = octv)*127.0+128.0)

        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.w/2,self.h/2,image=self.image)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.after(0, self.tr)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def tr(self):
        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.animate)
        self.t1.daemon = True
        self.t1.start()

    def animate(self):
        octv = 8
        freq = 16.0 * octv;
        while True:
            self.z += 0.01
            for y in xrange(self.h):
                for x in xrange(self.w):
                    self.pix[x,y] = int(snoise3(x/freq,y/freq,self.z,octaves = octv)*127.0+128.0)

            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
            self.canvas.create_image(self.w/2,self.h/2,image=self.image)
            self.canvas.pack()

Noise()
```

Thank you all ^^

Comment: I believe Tkinter is not thread safe so I'm quite surprised you are not getting more issues.  I'd guess the biggest issue is the nested loop to generate each pixel, would there be a way to do that part concurrently (like generate all the pixels at same time) then update the canvas in the main thread?

Comment: I think that would to the trick... But I don't want to mess up the code too much, dealing with lock and cuncurrency.

Comment: I think PyGame or Pyglet should be better than Tkinter. There are examples how to use it with Pyglet - see [noise doc](https://github.com/caseman/noise)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863967/pil-apply-the-same-operation-to-every-pixel