# How to apply an operation to every PIXEL (not every rgb component!) of a python image (either using numpy, opencv or PIL)?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to apply a function over all pixels of an image (in my specific case I want to do some colour approximation per pixel, but I don't think this is relevant for the problem) in an efficient way. The thing is that I've found different approaches to do so, but all of them apply a function over *each component* of a pixel, whereas what I want to do is to apply a function that *receives a pixel* (not a pixel component), this is, the 3 rgb components (I guess as a tuple, but I don't care about the format as long as I have the 3 components as parameters in my function).

If you are interested on what I have, this is the non-efficient solution to my issue (works fine but it is too slow):

```
def closest_colour(pixel, colours):
    closest_colours = sorted(colours, key=lambda colour: colours_distance(colour, pixel))
    return closest_colours[0]

# reduces the colours of the image based on the results of KMean
# img is image open with opencv.imread()
# colours is an array of colours
def image_color_reduction(img, colours):
    start = time.time()
    print("Color reduction...")
    reduced_img = img.copy()[...,::-1]
    width = reduced_img.shape[0]
    height = reduced_img.shape[1]
    
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            reduced_img[x,y] = closest_colour(reduced_img[x,y], colours)
    
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Successfully reduced in {end-start} seconds")
    return reduced_img
```

I've followed this post: [PIL - apply the same operation to every pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863967/pil-apply-the-same-operation-to-every-pixel) that seemed to be pretty clear and aligned with my issue. I've tried using any kind of image formatting, I've tried multithreading (both with pool.map & pool.imap), I've tried numpy.apply_along_axis and I finally tried PIL.point(), what I thought was the most similar solution to what I was looking for. Indeed, if you take a look at their official documentation: [.point()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point), it exactly says: *The function is called once for each possible pixel value*. I find this really misleading, because after trying it I realized  *pixel value* in this context does not refer to an rgb tuple, but to each of the 3 rgb compoments (seriously, in what world?).

I would really appreciate it if somebody could share a bit of their experience and give me some light on this issue. Thank you in advance!!

(UPDATE)

As per your request I add more information on the specific problem I am approaching:

> Given
>
> - an image M of size 1022*1080
> - an array of colours N with size 1 < |N| < 16
>
> Reduce the colours of M by replacing each pixel's colour by the most
> similar one in N (thanks to your answers I know this is defined as
> Nearest Neighbor Color Quantization)

This is the missing implementation of colours_distance:

```
def colours_distance(c1, c2):
    (r1,g1,b1) = c1
    (r2,g2,b2) = c2
    return math.sqrt((r1 - r2)**2 + (g1 - g2) ** 2 + (b1 - b2) **2)
```

And this are the imports needed to run this code:

```
import cv2
import time
import math
```

The solution shown in my question solves the problem described in slightly less than 40s on average.

Comment: why you don't slice the image into 3 2D arrays R G B and manipulate each of them, then you will be working on each pixel separately.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Is this the standard way of doing so? From my point of view having an operation for updating pixels seems like something pretty basic for an image processing library. Do I have to split the image channels whenever I want to do something like this?

Comment: *" Is this the standard way of doing so"* there is no standard way, it depends on the application, *"Do I have to split the image channels whenever I want to do something like this?"* maybe not, you can access pixel by pixel by splitting the channels of each pixel, or converting the whole image from RGB to Gray-scale, it depends on your application.

Comment: I actually spoke too soon. Your proposed solution doesn't help in my case as I need the 3 rgb components at once to compare the colour of the pixel against an arbitrary colour. I think the code snippet I attached is pretty self-explanatory for what I want to do. I need to apply an operation (colour comparison) on each pixel of an image, therefore I need to pass the whole pixel (the 3 colour channels) to the operation. Let me know if I can make use case more clear

Comment: Minor useful tidbit: `min()` also can take a comparison function, so you don't actually need to sort the list every time and take the 0th element, just use `min` :)

Comment: Also, I'm still a bit shocked after you said there is not a standard way of doing the same operation on a bunch of pixels. I mean, I can use .apply() on a pandas DataFrame independently of what there is in each cell. How I will approach each cell will depend on the content and the application as you mentioned, but still I consider the .apply() a generalized way of operating in a DataFrame. Isn't there anything like this for operating on pixels with PIL or OpenCV?

Comment: It would be nice to know what image processing are you going to do, and what for?

Comment: @Hihikomori OP gave the example of color quantization by nearest color

Comment: apply functions in numpy and pandas are generally running a python-level for loop under the hood. They are not even remotely vectorised. If you want something fast, show how you implement your functions.

Comment: Also, use `min` instead of sorting the entire array every time with `sorted`: `_, v = min((key(v), v) for v in blah)`

Comment: Please show the `colour_distance` function.

Comment: If you are unclear in your question, you will tend to not get the best answer. You don't appear to specify how big your image is in pixels, how long the processing currently takes, how many colours you are selecting from or what the algorithm `colours_distance` involves... you've also not provided a representative image and removed all your `import` statements so no-one can actually run your code.

Comment: Python is not the right language to implement algorithms that loop over an image, but it is the right language to call such algorithms from. You could try Numba to speed up your code.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers. You've shared a lot of theoretical concepts that are be really useful to me. As you mentioned the question was lacking some context, I added more information that I hope will be useful for anybody that reaches this post.

Comment: Note also that while `np.sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2)` gives you the actual length of a vector, you can normally omit the relatively expensive `np.sqrt()` and just compare the squared distances and still get the same result. E.g. if the actual distances are 2 and 3 units, the squared distances will be 4 and 9 so will the first one will still be closer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your image is an `(M, N, 3)` numpy array, your color table is `(K, 3)`, and you measure color distance as some sane vector norm, you can use scipy's [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) (or just [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)) to optimize and vectorize the lookup for you.

First make a tree out of your color table:

```
colors = ... # K, 3 array
color_tree = cKDTree(colors)
```

Now you can [`query`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) the tree directly to get the output image:

```
_, output = color_tree.query(img)
```

`output` will be an `(M, N)` index array into `color_table`. The important thing is that KD trees are optimized to perform `O(log K)` lookups per pixel, not `O(K)` or `O(K log K)` as in your current implementation. Since the loops are implemented in C, you'll get a major boost from that too.

Comment: Nice to know this exists. Is there a way to customize the distance measure?

Comment: @CrisLuengo. You can use different norms, but you can't specify an arbitrary function as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

### Note about "vectorization"

With numpy, there isn't a generic efficient way to apply an arbitrary function across some axis of your image. In order to do calculations efficiently, numpy needs to be able to do those calculations *in the backend* for you, not using Python at all. The same is true of OpenCV. When you call for e.g. `np.mean()` or `cv.meanStdDev()` or similar, these libraries are iterating through your images in C/C++/Fortran/etc so the code that gets executed needs to be *there*. However, you want to apply a function you've defined *in Python* on these values, which means you need to operate on Python objects directly, which removes all of the efficiency of doing operations in numpy/OpenCV/etc and is why there's no instantly fast way to do these calculations. You mentioned in your post about `df.apply()` from Pandas---note that `apply()` is actually slow, it does the looping in Python like you're currently doing, and generally you want to stay away from using it for that reason. Numpy and OpenCV don't expose a method like `apply()` *because* it is not really a good way to do things.

Generally, to do operations efficiently, you need to *vectorize* your code, which in Python-land means to only utilize built-in numpy/opencv/etc functions that can operate on your data all at once, without writing loops (or without them implicitly being called in Python, like `df.apply()`).

Note that nothing here is specific to working on pixels (or their individual components), this is a general problem in trying to achieve fast computations in Python. That is, even if any of the solutions you've tried were to work on a pixel (as opposed to components), it'd still be slow anyways.

### Solution

The specific problem you give as an example (nearest neighbor color quantization) is non-trivial to make fast, since for each pixel you need to figure out where you sit nearest in the list of colors. If you only have a few colors, like 8, it isn't terrible to just calculate the distance to all, but if you are trying to reduce the palette to 256 colors or something like that, it's a lot of compute. If you have only a few colors, then you can vectorize the whole operation by creating a 3d array representing the distance to each color at each x, y location, and taking the argmin across the color axis, which you can then use with a lookup table.

Here's an example implementation, reducing an image to 8 colors. We'll start with an image and some defined colors

```py
In [80]: img.shape
Out[80]: (90, 160, 3)

In [81]: colors
Out[81]:
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255,   0],
       [255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```

Now we want, for each pixel location in the image, the distance to each color (we'll use the abs diff distance function as an example, but any vectorizeable operation here will do). Here we can utilize broadcasting to get a resulting array of shape `(h, w, n_colors)`:

```py
In [83]: distances = np.sum(np.abs(img[..., np.newaxis] - colors.T), axis=2)

In [84]: distances.shape
Out[84]: (90, 160, 8)
```

Now you want to know which color resulted in the minimum distance for each pixel:

```py
In [87]: nearest_colors = np.argmin(distances, axis=2)

In [88]: nearest_colors
Out[88]:
array([[7, 4, 3, ..., 2, 2, 4],
       [5, 7, 6, ..., 3, 2, 5],
       [5, 3, 7, ..., 3, 5, 7],
       ...,
       [6, 5, 0, ..., 7, 6, 1],
       [1, 6, 5, ..., 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 7, 5, 4]])
```

So at the first pixel, the closest color was the last one in my color list (all white), at the next pixel to the right the closest color was `[255, 255, 0]`, and so on. Now you can use a lookup table to map from these to their actual color values. The way to do this with numpy is to use fancy indexing:

```py
In [91]: quantized = colors[nearest_colors]

In [92]: quantized.shape
Out[92]: (90, 160, 3)
```

And here's your image with the new quantized colors.

A more efficient solution for this problem is to utilize a kd-tree, as [MadPhysicist answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497145/5087436). However, color distance functions can be non-linear and those distances may not map well to spatial data structures, in which case there's usually specialized implementations or very specific ways in which to make them faster, but this is closer to research and not appropriate for SO.

For other color quantization algorithms, this question has a lot of good examples: [Fast color quantization in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv/49715101)

Comment: You can do a searchsorted on the entire array, or an indexed lexsort. You almost never need to exceed N log N.

Comment: @MadPhysicist How does searchsorted map to a kd-tree?

Comment: It may not map directly. I wasn't really thinking too hard when I said searchsorted, although kdtree is a generalization of multidimensional sorting

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution if it will be faster:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
result = np.zeros_like(img)
colors_arr = [[0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 255], [255, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0]]
#  Normalizing images and colors to 1.
colors = np.array(colors_arr, np.float32) / 255
img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255

#  For each color making an array of weights.
weights = []
for i in range(colors.shape[0]):
    weights.append(np.sum(np.square(img - colors[i]), axis=2))

weights = np.array(weights, np.float32)
#  Finding the index of minimum weight
weights = np.transpose(weights, axes=[1, 2, 0])
color_inds = np.argmin(weights, axis=2)

# Depending on minimum weight index assigning the color to the result
for i in range(len(colors_arr)):
    idx = np.where(color_inds == i)
    result[idx] = colors_arr[i]

cv2.imshow('', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This solution may not be as fast as you expect.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. For very large images, it would be more efficient to build a 3D lookup table, basically apply your code to a list of all possible colors (with reduced precision to reduce the size of computation), then  index with the RGB values for each image pixel into that table to find the mapped color. It’s more involved, but requires fewer distance computations if the table has fewer elements than the image has pixels.

Comment: @Mad Physicist The bottleneck here is np.where call for each color index.

Comment: You don't really need either of these for loops; for the first you can use broadcasting, for the second you can use fancy indexing directly as a LUT.

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in the relative performance of using `linalg.norm()` versus the `cKDTree()` for your dataset sizes of 1022x1080 image with N (palette length) in the range 1..16.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

def QuantizeToGivenPalette(im, palette):
    """Quantize image to a given palette.
    
    The input image is expected to be a Numpy array.
    The palette is expected to be a list of R,G,B values."""

    # Calculate the distance to each palette entry from each pixel
    distance = np.linalg.norm(im[:,:,None].astype(np.float) - palette[None,None,:].astype(np.float), axis=3)

    # Now choose whichever one of the palette colours is nearest for each pixel
    palettised = np.argmin(distance, axis=2).astype(np.uint8)

    return palettised

################################################################################
# main
################################################################################

# Let's get some repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(42)

# Open a colorwheel, resize to match dimensions of question
M = 1022, 1080
im = cv2.imread('colorwheel.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
im = cv2.resize(im, M, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Make a full 256-entry palette of random colours, but we'll just use the first N
palette = np.random.randint(0,256,(256,3),dtype=np.uint8)

# Try quantizing with linalg.norm, for various palette lengths
pLengths = [4,8,12,16]
for pLength in pLengths:

    indices = QuantizeToGivenPalette(im, palette[:pLength])

    # Write image of just palette indices
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-indices-linalg{pLength}.png', indices)

    # Look up each pixel in the palette and revert to BGR and save
    BGR = palette[indices]
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-result-linalg{pLength}.png', BGR)

################################################################################
# NOW DO SAME THING BUT WITH KDTREE
################################################################################

from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# Try quantizing with cKDTree, for various palette lengths
for pLength in pLengths:

    # Build our tree from the palette, only necessary once for any given palette
    treeFromPalette = cKDTree(palette[:pLength])

    # Lookup nearest indices for each pixel in image
    _, indices = treeFromPalette.query(im)

    # Write image of just palette indices
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-indices-cKDTree{pLength}.png', indices)

    # Look up each pixel in the palette and revert to BGR and save
    BGR = palette[indices]
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-result-cKDTree{pLength}.png', BGR)
```

---

I used this image as input and resized it to your stated dimensions:

[image]

The results were the same for both methods:

4 colours:

[image]

8 colours:

[image]

16 colours:

[image]

---

The interesting thing was the timings - all in milliseconds:

```
N      norm()  cKDTree()
4      147     485
8      307     308
12     449     530
16     601     542
```

If we plot those, you can see that `cKDTree()` only really comes into its own at the higher end of your N-values:

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, KDTree, linalg.norm, palette, quantisation, prime.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks for doing the timing.