# pillow. how do I convert an image to a specific, defined palette

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, palette

I need to convert an image to specific palette. It does not not need to use all the colours in that palette but it must not in any circumstances use colours from outside it.

I also need to reduce the number of colours in the image to a defined number - say 10.

I have tried all versions of image.quantize() and in each case they completely change the defined palette. After going round in circles for days I thought it is time to ask for advice :)

Addition: running quantise without a quantisation method does maintain the palette - but does not reduce the number of colours. Looking at the output from getpixel, running it without a method does not seem to amend the image in any way.

```
from PIL import Image

# palette contains 20 unique colours and is padded out to 256 colours to avoid
#being automatically padded with random greycale colours.
palette=[255, 223, 213, 199, 43, 59, 210, 16, 53, 253, 156, 151, 250, 50, 3,
         253, 93, 53, 227, 29, 66, 255, 139, 0, 247, 203, 191, 255, 223, 217,
         255, 238, 235, 209, 88, 7, 235, 99, 7, 255, 123, 77, 255, 222, 213,
         247, 139, 19, 252, 171, 152, 217, 137, 120, 254, 205, 194, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252,
         252, 252, 252]


pImg=Image.new("P",(16, 16))
pImg.putpalette(palette)
print("\n\n\npImg palette: "+ str(pImg.getpalette()))

# open the image which I want to convert to the new palette
sourceImg= Image.open("whirl.png")
sourceImg=sourceImg.convert("RGB")
sourceImg.thumbnail(size=(100, 100))

#force the source image to use the new palette
sourceImg=sourceImg.quantize(palette=pImg,dither=0)
print("sourceImg mode: "+ str(sourceImg.mode))
print("sourceImg palette: "+ str(sourceImg.getpalette()))

#quant=sourceImg.copy()
sourceImg=sourceImg.quantize(colors=10,method=2,kmeans=10) 
print("sourceImg mode: "+ str(sourceImg.mode))
print("sourceImg palette: "+ str(sourceImg.getpalette()))
```

Output:

```
pImg palette: [255, 223, 213, 199, 43, 59, 210, 16, 53, 253, 156, 151, 250, 50, 3, 253, 93, 53, 227, 29, 66, 255, 139, 0, 247, 203, 191, 255, 223, 217, 255, 238, 235, 209, 88, 7, 235, 99, 7, 255, 123, 77, 255, 222, 213, 247, 139, 19, 252, 171, 152, 217, 137, 120, 254, 205, 194, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252]
sourceImg mode: P
sourceImg palette: [255, 223, 213, 199, 43, 59, 210, 16, 53, 253, 156, 151, 250, 50, 3, 253, 93, 53, 227, 29, 66, 255, 139, 0, 247, 203, 191, 255, 223, 217, 255, 238, 235, 209, 88, 7, 235, 99, 7, 255, 123, 77, 255, 222, 213, 247, 139, 19, 252, 171, 152, 217, 137, 120, 254, 205, 194, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252, 252]
sourceImg mode: P
sourceImg palette: [228, 34, 29, 238, 97, 16, 254, 226, 219, 252, 165, 151, 255, 123, 77, 247, 203, 191, 217, 137, 120, 227, 29, 66, 247, 139, 19, 252, 252, 252, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66534376/2836621

Comment: Thanks Mark. The article will take me a while to get my head around (both in terms of the code and the approach) but it certainly looks like a good steer :)

Comment: Thanks Mark - that was really useful and did the job nicely.