# Python: better performance, PIL/Numpy replace multiple RGB colors from list (RGB palette)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My function works but with poor efficiency and time-consuming *for loops* in comparing RGB Images pixels...

So, the below function takes PNG filename and two thresholds to reduce the image's colors concerning image quality by comparing the reduced colors image (assume 255 RGB colors generated in 1st step) with the original image in nested **for loops**, (2nd step to don't mess up sensitive image pixels with scattered colors).
I put the *closest* and *is_replaceable* functions according to the good posts I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244301/2128759):

```
def reduce_colors_sensitive_respect(image_file, max_colors=255, threshold1=10, threshold2=20):
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    org_image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
    
    # Use libimagequant to make a palette for the RGBA pixels 
    # and get converted PNG file as PIL RGB Image
    reduced_image = reduce_png_palette_ex(org_image, max_colors=max_colors)

    width, height = org_image.size

    output_img_sensitive = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), white)

    idx = 0
    changed = 0

    # iterate through each pixel in the images by given threshold
    # and save if difference is above threshold
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            idx += 1
            rgb_1 = org_image.getpixel((x, y))
            rgb_2 = reduced_image.getpixel((x, y))

            if not is_replaceable(rgb_1, rgb_2, threshold1):
                changed += 1
                output_img_sensitive.putpixel((x, y), rgb_1)

            log_reduce_progress(changed, height, width, idx, x, y)

    output_img_sensitive = reduce_png_palette_ex(output_img_sensitive, max_colors=max_colors)
    color_count = get_colors_count(output_img_sensitive)

    idx = 0
    changed = 0
    output_img_sensitive_colors = list(get_colors_count(output_img_sensitive).keys())
    output_img_sensitive_colors = list(filter(white.__ne__, output_img_sensitive_colors))

    # iterate through the reduced color image and replace each white pixel
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            idx += 1
            rgb_reduced = reduced_image.getpixel((x, y))
            rgb_sensitive = output_img_sensitive.getpixel((x, y))

            if rgb_sensitive == white:
                changed += 1
                found_color = closest(output_img_sensitive_colors, rgb_reduced)
                color = found_color if is_replaceable(found_color, rgb_reduced, threshold2) else rgb_reduced
                output_img_sensitive.putpixel((x, y), color)

            log_reduce_progress(changed, height, width, idx, x, y)

    return output_img_sensitive
```

```
def closest(colors, color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors - color) ** 2, axis=1))
    index_of_smallest = np.where(distances == np.amin(distances))
    smallest_distance = tuple(colors[index_of_smallest][0])
    return smallest_distance


def is_replaceable(color1, color2, threshold):
    r, g, b = color1
    cr, cg, cb = color2
    return sqrt((r - cr) ** 2 + (g - cg) ** 2 + (b - cb) ** 2) <= threshold
```

As you can guess, the problem is too slow and poor efficiency in **nested loops**, Can you suggest a solution to avoid iterating in for loops?

***UPDATE:***

---

As per your request, I add more information about the images attributes and my goal...

- **Specifications of the images I want to process:**

The input images are usually famous paintings with large pixel dimensions and many colors that have lost their quality due to age and have scratches, unrelated lines, and points that have been created in the paintings over time.

For example: [A Boyar Wedding Feast (Konstantin Makovsky, 1883)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/A_Boyar_Wedding_Feast_%28Konstantin_Makovsky%2C_1883%29_Google_Cultural_Institute.jpg)

> Size: 11464x6890, Depth: 24bit, Colors: 428638

- **My Goal:**

In addition to reducing the dimensions of the image while maintaining the ratio of length and width, I want to reduce the number of colors in the image to a maximum of 200 colors and in a better case below 100 colors, in a way that the *color continuity* of the image is not lost and the Irrelevant colors that do not exist in the main image, especially the face and hands, should not be included.

- **What I did in summary:**

*Intro.*

In the steps before these functions, I have to reduce the dimensions of the image at first, which does not cause a problem, but when reducing the color, many unrelated colors have been inserted in unwanted places, especially in the faces, hands, ... of people.
By scattered and unrelated colors I mean the colors that the human eye can easily recognize the difference between them before and after the color reduction. This first threshold number is a relative value that I get from the closest function, and I experimentally set it between 7 and 10.

*So:*

1. First, I read and convert the Image to RGB PNG (lossless format), then reduce the colors to the desired number, which made unwanted color changes in the image!
2. Create a palette of points that have passed the first threshold (that is, their RGB distance from the RGB of the similar pixel in the original image is greater than the first threshold), I put white color instead of the rest of the pixels (*time-consuming* due to nested loops)
3. Another experimental threshold is set for white points (non-specific), for the white points that I placed in the reduced color image, I look for close points in the previous palette and if the second threshold is not passed, I replace them, otherwise In this case, I put the color from the reduced image.(*time-consuming* too)

Result:

> Size: 2866x1723, Depth: 8bit, Colors: 247

---

Due to the limitation of the image size, I will put a sample for comparison:

[image: Original image sample after size reduction (72 dpi> 18 dpi)]

> Size: 291x231, Depth: 24bit, Colors: 48936

[image: Reduced colored image]

> Size: 291x231, Depth: 8bit, Colors: 184

- **Desired Goal:** *I want the image to be smoothed with the least number of colors, even if the edges and sharpness of the image are reduced, what is important is color stretch and its continuity are provided with the least number of colors.*

Comment: One trivial way to speed up computations is to avoid the `sqrt` in `sqrt((r - cr) ** 2 + (g - cg) ** 2 + (b - cb) ** 2) <= threshold`. Instead compare against the square of `threshold`. But the loops and the calls to `getpixel` and `putpixel` surely are much more expensive in Python.

Comment: You are right @cris, but the sqrt time is nothing compared to that nested loops...

Comment: Yeah, in Python it likely is not relevant. In a compiled language that is the typical thing slowing down a program… :)

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm not familiar with PIL to understand what your code is doing. Can you please provide a small sample image to test with and maybe explain more about what you're doing?

Comment: I think it will not be trivial to vectorize this code. I would convert the images to NumPy arrays before the double loop, work exclusively with NumPy, and then use Numba to speed it up (it compiles the code for you).

Comment: Don't do `np.where(distances == np.amin(distances))`. Use `np.argmin()` instead.

Comment: It's not clear what sort of images you are trying to process - in terms of dimensions, content, number of colours. Nor what the special significance is of white and scattered and special pixels. Nor what values you are using for thresholds or why. Nor what results you expect. Maybe you could update your question with some details.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66534376/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53482138/2836621

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I'll try to implement your suggestions, but due to my short Numpy skills, it will be difficult to change the entire code to it because other functions are also called in this function.

Comment: thanks, @MarkSetchell, I'll update the post as you want

Comment: Please don't think of it as pleasing me! It's to try and get the best response for you.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try with `numba` which will compile  your barely changed Python into multi-threaded, SIMD-optimised code. Try putting `[numba]` into the StackOverflow search box for examples. You can parallelise across multiple CPU-cores by making your outer loop use `for y in prange(height)` for a parallel range. You can convert your PIL Image into a Numpy array using `na = np.array(yourPILImage)` and `number` can work directly with the Numpy array. You can convert the resulting Numpy array back into a PIL Image with `pillmage = Image.fromarray(numpyArray)` at the end.