# Replacing for loops with numpy functions to reduce image dimensions and number of colors

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, reshape

First of all, I'm relatively new to Python and its libraries.
I'm trying to loop through all the pixels of an image using Pillow to divide an image into a fraction of the original dimensions, by take the closest RGB color for the division matrix from all the colors of the original image.
With the following function, this takes more than *three hours* for an average image with a large number of colors:

```
def divide_image_by_rgb(image_file, division=4):
    input_img = Image.open(image_file)
    width, height = input_img.size
    pixels_count = width * height

    if division < 2:
        raise Exception("Invalid division!")

    white = (255, 255, 255)
    width_out = width // division
    height_out = height // division
    output_img = Image.new('RGB', (width_out, height_out), white)
    all_colors = list(get_colors_count(input_img).keys())

    for x in range(width_out):
        for y in range(height_out):
            pixels = []
            [r, g, b] = [0, 0, 0]
            for d1 in range(division):
                for d2 in range(division):
                    pos_x = x * division + d1
                    pos_y = y * division + d2
                    if pos_x > width or pos_y > height:
                        continue

                    pixel = input_img.getpixel((pos_x, pos_y))
                    pixels.append(pixel)
                    r += pixel[0] ** 2
                    g += pixel[1] ** 2
                    b += pixel[2] ** 2

            div = division ** 2
            mean_color = (
                round(sqrt(r // div)),
                round(sqrt(g // div)),
                round(sqrt(b // div))
            )
            mean_color = closest(all_colors, mean_color)
            output_img.putpixel((x, y), mean_color)
            # log_reduce_progress(changed, pixels_count, height, width, idx, x, y)

    output_file = f"resized.[{division}].{os.path.basename(image_file)}"

    output_img.save(output_file)
    return output_file



def closest(colors, color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors - color) ** 2, axis=1))
    index_of_smallest = np.where(distances == np.amin(distances))
    smallest_distance = tuple(colors[index_of_smallest][0])
    return smallest_distance
```

**Goal**: I want to replace explicit loops using numpy

**Input image**: The input image is something like this:

> PNG, Size: (6.32MP) Dimensions: 2228x2836, Depth: 24bit, Colors count: 632576

**Result**:

> PNG, Size: (0.39MP) Dimensions: 557x709, Depth: 24bit, Colors count: 110896

**Why**: I want reduce image dimensions and colors to be smoothed with the least number of colors, the hue, uniformity and composition of the image should not be lost. I use *libimagequant*, *quantize ADAPTIVE*, reduce colors from given *RGB palette* csv, etc. before, but this method gives me the closest color combination to the desired result, I use result image as RGB palette to reduce original Image colors with respect to main colors.

**Try:**
I tried to do this with numpy functions which failed and with every change, my errors and confusion increase:

```
def resize_image_manual_ex(image_file, division=4):

    input_img = Image.open(image_file)
    width, height = input_img.size
    pixels_count = width * height

    white = (255, 255, 255)
    width_out = width // division
    height_out = height // division
    output_img = Image.new('RGB', (width_out, height_out), white)

    # Convert the input image to a NumPy array
    input_array = np.array(input_img)

    # Use NumPy's reshaping to create sub-images
    sub_images = input_array.reshape(height_out, division, width_out, division, 3)

    # Calculate the mean color of each sub-image
    mean_colors = np.mean(sub_images, axis=(1, 3))

    # Find the closest color for each mean color
    all_colors = list(get_colors_count(input_img).keys())
    closest_colors = [closest(all_colors, color) for color in mean_colors]

    for x in range(width_out):
        for y in range(height_out):
            output_img.putpixel((x, y), closest_colors[y, x])

    output_file = f"resized.[{division}].{os.path.basename(image_file)}"

    output_img.save(output_file)
    return output_file
```

**Last error:**

> sub_images = input_array.reshape(height_out, division, width_out, division, 3)

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 56925 into shape (57,2,82,2,3)

Is there any way to replace *for* loops with numpy (or any else) to reduce the running time?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks to be a rounding error due to the integer division performed to get the sub-image sizes, as the number of values in the desired shape are a little under the input size. Have you tried cropping the images first to make sure the dimensions are a multiple of the scaledown factor?

Comment: @DanielF OP is already using the quadratic mean suggested as the top answer in your link.

Comment: This looks the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76661035/2836621 How did you get on with the suggested responses to that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell When using numba, I came across many errors that due to the use of nested functions, I had to change my entire structure which naturally increased the number of errors. also in the first step, I had to apply numpy in my codes. this question was raised in that regard.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal some pixels are placed outside the scaledown factor when dividing the image, which I ignore them in my loops, I can't figure out how to do this in numpy, that's why I couldn't test it by cropping image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want, I think.  I'm not to clear on `PIL` commands, so check those.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import os

def divide_image_by_rgb(image_file, division=4):
    """this is all PIL stuff, ask another question if this doesn't work"""
    input_img = Image.open(image_file)

    if division < 2:
        raise Exception("Invalid division!")

    np_image = np.array(input_img)
    mean_img = mean_divide_np_image(np_image, division)

    output_img = Image.fromarray(mean_img)
    output_file = f"resized.[{division}].{os.path.basename(image_file)}"

    output_img.save(output_file)
    
    return output_file

def mean_divide_np_image(input_img, division):
    width, height, _ = input_img.shape
    width_out = width // division
    height_out = height // division
    np_image = np.array(input_img)[:width_out * division, :height_out * division]
    all_colors = np.unique(np_image.reshape(-1, 3), axis = 0)
    img_blocks = view_as_blocks(np_image, (width_out, height_out, 3))
    mean_img = np.mean(img_blocks**2, axis = (0, 1, 2))
    mean_img = np.sqrt(closest(all_colors**2, mean_img)).astype(input_img.dtype)
    
    return mean_img

def closest(colors, img):
    color_tree = KDTree(colors)
    dist, i = color_tree.query(img)
    closest_color = colors[i]
    return closest_color
```

Big things I did:

- vectorized the mean function, so it's not going pixel by pixel.  Also used a `view` from `view_as_blocks` to save memory.  Maintained the root mean squared functionality needed to average RGB values, also carrying the squares through the `closest` search.
- Changed `closest` to a `KDTree` functionality.  This is *much* faster for large numbers of colors

Comment: Thank you for devoting your time to answering question, but in view_as_blocks I get this Error:

ValueError: 'block_shape' is not compatible with 'arr_in'

Comment: Check now.  I don't know anything about PIL so if that function doesn't work ask another question, my stuff works and is tested with `numpy` arrays

Comment: Nice answer When you convert your Numpy array `mean_img` into a PIL Image, you need to make sure it is of type `np.uint8` and with shape (height, width, 3) if you want it to be an RGB PIL Image... I suspect yours is still `np.float` at this line `output_image=Image.fromarray(mean_img)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell added an `astype` to the end of the `numpy` function for that, thanks.